# What is the format of an SQL like query using Google Visualisation API in Google App Script?

Tags: sql, google-visualization

I am currently trying to get the below "Select count" query to work but right now it's not working:

```
query.setQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE O = Parent and AK = Production');
```

A normal query like this one works fine:

```
query.setQuery('SELECT A,B,C');
```

Can anyone please tell me if complex queries can be executed using Google Visualization API or if there is a syntax error in the above query?

Any suggestions/links to resources will be much appreciated.

Comment: have you seen [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#queryobjects)? also, what do `Parent` and `Production` refer to?

Comment: @WhiteHat Yes, I have and Parent and production refer to values in columns O and AK respectively.

Comment: if those are values you are testing for, they should be in single quotes --> `query.setQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE O = 'Parent' and AK = 'Production'");`